# How to handle multiple parameters with ObjectMapper?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I would like to know how one tests a controller (post) which requires multiple arguments.

```
@RequestMapping(value = PATH_TO_OBFUSCATED, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> download(@RequestBody String requestBody, @RequestParam("obfuscated") boolean obfiscated) {
    return obfuscated.download(requestBody, obfiscated);
}
```

I know, when I am testing a spring mvc controller with one param, I can use ObjectMapper like so:

```
.content(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(obfuscated))
```

But, how should I use the ObjectMapper when there's >=2?

Comment: You shouldn't. As 1 is the body and the request only has 1 body the other is a regular reguest parameter. Which you can add using `param(name, value)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments you have just 1 body. So maybe something like this:

```
 this.mockMvc.perform(
        post("/obfuscated").
            contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
            content(json).// <-- the body
            param("obfuscated", "true"))// <-- the param
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
```